# Spatial не содержит определения transform - Godot Engine

Tags: godot

Начинаю разбираться в Godot Engine, пишу на C# и столкнулся с ошибкой "Spatial не содержит определения transform" в коде:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Camera : Node
{
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        Spatial.transform.origin = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }

    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {

    }
}
```

В [документации](https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/stable/tutorials/3d/using_transforms.html#introduction) написано:

[image]

*"Каждый узел Spatial имеет свойство transform"* - значит Spatial.transform существует, чему противоречит данная ошибка

С чем это связано и как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

эта ошибка возможна в том случае, если у Ваш узел камеры не назван 'Spatial'. если Вы прикрепили этот скрипт к камере, как видно из названия класса, попробуйте модифицировать `transform.origin`  без `Spatial`.

Comment: `transform.origin = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);` - Имя "transform" не существует в данном контексте

Comment: хм. через gdscript, если я хотел редактировать какое-то свойство узла, я без ссылки на узел просто модифицировал его. необходимо, значит, как-то верно ссылаться на узел с трансформ, который нужно изменять.

Comment: Камера имеет узел Spatial, который имеет transform

Comment: тогда нужно ссылаться на этот узел, и затем только изменить свойство. Node = GetNode<NodeClassName>('NodeName'). Node.transform.origin = value